# Add live to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add `.live` to the to the following function?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.fn.vAlign = function() {
    return this.each(function(i){
        var ah = $(this).height();
        var mh = (368 - ah) / 2;
    $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
    });
};
$('div.slideshow img').vAlign();
});
```

I need to add `live` because `div.slideshow img` is being generated by jQuery. The function doesn't seem to work unless the div is already in HTML prior to the script being executed.

Comment: Just call `.vAlign` on any newly created elements after you insert them to the DOM.

Comment: As always, please use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.live()` if using jQuery 1.7 or greater.

Comment: Can you add your call to vAlign() in the same jQuery code that generates the img?  Or at least, trigger a custom event within that img generation code, that you could then bind to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

```
 $('div.slideshow img').livequery(function(){ $(this).vAlign(); });
```

this will make it so vAlign() gets executed on any element that matches your selection on load and anytime after.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `.live`, `.delegate` or `.on` would help you in this case. What you can probably do is run `$('div.slideshow img').vAlign();` in the callback after the ajax response is successful and the images have been injected into the DOM.